# LXTerminal shortcuts work but also output to console

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I installed a netinst of Debian 6, `xorg`, `lxde` and `lxterminal`.

When I press `Ctrl+Shift+T` in the terminal, I get a new tab as expected, but the new tab also displays `^T` before the prompt. The same for `Ctrl+Shift+C`, it copies the selected text to clipboard, but also sends the key combination to the console.

Why? How do I make the terminal respond to commands without sending them to the console?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39573/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxterminal/+bug/1080116

In short, I had the same problem and so went to the code and fixed it.
LXTerminal is an hack, it is a shame that such software is considered a terminal.

You need to fix the code yourself, or I suggest you abandon LXDE and use a decent terminal under GNOME or KDE, for example.

I am abandoning LXDE for the same reason, it is a regression on all aspects.